# How to give IBAction event to custom cell's UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to give custom cell's UIButton IBAction event.

I tried with below code but it crashes.

How can I create delegate & use that in my UITableView class?

`Customcell class`

```
-(IBAction)btnShowAttachmentClick:(UITableView *)aTblViewCommon
{
    [(ShowTechAndProfDetailsVC *)aTblViewCommon.delegate performSelector:@selector(showAttachmentsFromCell:) withObject:nil];
}
```

`UIViewController class having UITableView`

```
-(void)showAttachmentsFromCell:(UIButton *)sender
{
    gotoClass *obj = [[gotoClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"gotoClass" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
    [obj release];
}
```

Here is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
    if(appDelegate.intCountSwipeForView == 1 || appDelegate.intCountSwipeForView == 2)
    {
        objCellView = [ViewExpAndEduCustomCell dequeOrCreateInTable:tableView];

        objCellView.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //objCellView.btnPaperClip.tag = indexPath.row;
        [objCellView.btnPaperClip addTarget:self action:@selector(showAttachmentsFromCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        objCellView.lblName.text = @"asdfsdf";
        objCellView.lblTitleOrCourse.text = @"asdf";
        objCellView.lblStartDate.text = @"23-Nov-2001";
        objCellView.lblEndDate.text = @"04-Feb-2002";


        [objCellView.txtViewSummary setTextColor:TEXT_COLOR_GRAY_FOR_TABLECELL];
        [objCellView.txtViewSummary setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];
        [objCellView.txtViewSummary setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, 0, 0, 0)];
        [objCellView.txtViewSummary setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [objCellView.txtViewSummary setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    }
if(appDelegate.intCountSwipeForView == 1){
        objCellView.txtViewSummary.text = @"Experience.This is sample text.This text can be of 150 characters.No more than that.You can also attach your achievment but only pdf,Image or video";
        return objCellView;
}
```

Comment: show code where you are calling the method..in tableview

Comment: I am not calling in tableview.I just call in performselector of tableviewcell class

Comment: Have you tried it with TableView's accessory view with UIButton ?

Comment: I am using custom cell so used a UIButton in UITableViewCell's IB

Comment: @Roshni your code is looking fine just check the connection between button and your custom class is made properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey have an `IBOutlet` of you button in `Customcell` class then in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //creating cell or resusing cell

    //after getting the cell and casting it into your Customcell
        [cell.mButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAttachmentsFromCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Comment: It is not going inside selector method

Comment: I have taken IBOutlet for that button in UITableViewCell class.and called method in UITableView's class

Comment: I think i need to create delegate

Comment: @roshini wthr u have made property for btnPaperClip in objCellView and synthesized it..?